# How do I add target=“_blank” to a link within a div with an specific class name?

Tags: javascript, class, hyperlink, target

I´m trying to add target=“_blank” to all the links within the divs with an specific class name. I know how to do it with an ID:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementById('link_other').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}
```

But i´m trying to replicate the same, using classes instead of IDS. Any ideas of a how to do this without jquery?.

Thanks in davanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll() and include a CSS selector. So if your class name is link-other:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.link-other a')
  .forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  })
```

```html
<div class="link-other"> 
  <a href="http://wikipedia.com">Wikipedia</a>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2965583 You should accept the most helpful answer.

Comment: This will not work as `.forEach` is not a method on a NodeList.

Comment: @andlrc You are mistaken. forEach() is a prototype method of Array. querySelectAll() returns an instance of Array. Click on `Run code snippet` to see that this does indeed work. For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Martin: yet [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) contradicts you. `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` according to the DOM spec.

Comment: @Martin: perhaps you have [extended the NodeList prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Workarounds)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) which takes a css expression:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.my_class a');
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
  anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

Or (ab)using the array prototype:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.my_class a'), function(el) {
  el.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
});
```

You should also consider using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `window.onload`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Or the more appropriate:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // ...
});
```

You can also use the old school `<base>` element which will can set defaults for all a tags:

```
var base_el = document.createElement('base');
base_el.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
document.head.appendChild(base_el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` and loop just like you did.

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".link_other a");
```

Or you can use `getElementsByClassName` and nested loops.

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName(".link_other");
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    var anchors = parents[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) {
        anchors[j].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result use below option

```
        var addList = document.querySelectorAll('.link_other a');

    for(var i in addList){
     addList[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
```

Codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEEvPR

Hope it works

Comment: Updated the codepen with additional URLs with class link_other and few links without link_other class .And updated class as "link_other" to match with your code..Please find updated codepen URL below
 http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEEvPR
Hope this works for you :)

Comment: cool...can you mark as this question as answered or vote if possible :)